# Complexity to transform any graph into planar using barycenters

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I am working on transforming any graph into a planar graph.

I have just come across this algorithmic exercise, which I can't solve :

```
 while G is not planar do
   for all x vertex of G do 
      V = list of x's neighbors
      M =  barycenter of the vertexes of V
      if we decrease the number of arc intersections then 
         then place x in M
      endif 
   endfor
 end while
```

1. What is the complexity of this algorithm ? I have no idea, however I would say that it depends on the number of edges and vertexes.
2. Does the loop always end ? No, the planar graph has to have an Euler's cycle to be a planar graph. If it doesn't the loop will never stop.

Any help in this subject will be appreciated

Comment: If the loop could potentially never end then the worst-case complexity clearly is infinite. Probably the case of interest is for planar graph only?

Comment: You can add a stopping criteria: If at a given step, for all x, you don't decrease the number of intersections, then you stop. With it, you are sure to stop at the end: the total number of intersections will decrease, and is lower bounded by 0.

Comment: @mapto I agree with you. But it's for the general complexity where I'm blocking :/

Comment: @Damien Yep, that could be an improved version, but it's not required. But it's a good remark

Comment: In order to determine the overall complexity, one of the things you need to know is what is the complexity of checking whether the graph is planar. However, this seems to be a difficult ([possibly unsolved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71856/checking-whether-a-graph-is-planar)) problem in the general case.

Comment: Testing whether a graph has a planar embedding is [doable in linear time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planarity_testing). Boost has a nice implementation.